# awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'

Tags: awk

```
echo "A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\" | awk -F'[:\]' '{print $1}'
```

Output:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'

A
```

I am getting the above warning message, I have tried multiple options to escape the `]` but that didn't resolve.

I want to use both the delimiters `:\` and print exactly the alphabets `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` by printing `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4` respectively.

Comment: Is your field separator: 1) *either* a colon *or* a backslash, or 2) a two character string "colon-backslash"? If it's the latter: `echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F ':\\\\' -v OFS=- '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'` gives
`A- B- C- D-`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you improve the question so that people can address directly to your specific issue?

Comment: Apologies for not making my point clear, Here what i am trying to do is, i would need to use both the delimiters ":\" and print exactly the alphabets A B C D by printing $1 $2 $3 $4 respectively.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F':\\\\[[:space:]]*' '{print $2}'
B
```

Note that I added `[[:space:]]*` as I don't think you want leading spaces in the fields after `$1`.

String literals as used in your `FS` setting get parsed twice, once when the script is read and again when executed so escapes need to be doubled up (google it and/or read the awk man page or book). In this case on the first pass `\\\\` gets converted to `\\` and on the second pass `\\` gets converted to `\` which is what you want.

Comment: echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F':\\\\[[:space:]]+' '{print $4}'      output : D:\
need to escape here as well

Comment: @user3834663 no, it's not about escaping anything, it just should be `*` instead of `+` after the `[[:space:]]` to allow for there being no spaces. Corrected now thanks.

Comment: The Open Group clarifies that the C-style string preprocessing applies to regular expression strings.  It stops short of explicitly saying that awk interprets contents of all string variables (not just that of constants) before invoking the regex interpreter.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04 

$ f='\\.(dll|exe)$'

$ awk -v filemask="${f}" 'BEGIN { a = "foodll"; print (a ~ filemask); print filemask;}'
0
\.(dll|exe)$

Comment: After some thought, I realized awk would not apply preprocessing over and over again.  The preprocessing appears to apply only to constants including those in the -v NAME=VALUE option.

$ echo '\.(dll|exe)' | awk '{ filemask=$0; } END { a = "foo.dll"; if (length(filemask) > 0) { print (a ~ filemask); print filemask; } ;}'
1
\.(dll|exe)

$ echo '\.(dll|exe)' | awk '{ filemask=$0; } END { a = "foodll"; if (length(filemask) > 0) { print (a ~ filemask); print filemask; } ;}'
0
\.(dll|exe)

Comment: Thanks, the fact that the FS is parsed twice was not clear to me, I use awk since 25 years and never got that impression from the documentation...

Comment: You're welcome. The explanation is in the documentation but it's in 3 parts: a) FS is a type of regexp, b) a dynamic regexp (i.e. a regexp specified as a string `"foo"` instead of literal `/foo/`) is parsed twice, and c) FS is always specified as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This is also wrong:

```
echo "A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\"
```

You are escaping the `"` and it breaks the input, you need to remove it or use single quote.

`awk` does not like a single `\` within field separator, so try:

```
echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F":|\\" '{print $1}'
A
```

Or you can escape it (single quote):

```
echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F'[:\\\\]' '{print $1}'
A
```

Or even more escaping (double quote):

```
echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F"[:\\\\\\\]" '{print $1}'
A
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj When adding code tags to OPs post it now show the problem "\" within the `-F"[:\]"`  here it escapes the `]` and give the warning OP writes.

Comment: i think op want to use :\ as FS.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Then it would be some like this `echo 'A:\ B:\ C:\ D:\' | awk -F':\\\' '{print $1}'`.  But since he uses square brackets, its for me this or that.