# awk and special brackets delimiters

Tags: linux, awk, delimiter

I have data in the following format:

```
.......{INFO1}.....[INFO2]....
```

For `awk` it should be really simple to pick up the `INFO1` and `INFO2` parts, but I'm really struggling with it.

I have managed to get the `[INFO2]` part by using `awk -F'[][]' '{ print $2 }'` but the `INFO1` just will not match for me.

How do I specify `{}` as delimiters?

Comment: It would be helpful to show a full line of your data

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `[][{}]` to define that you can use either of these: `[`, `]`, `{` or `}` as field separators

```
awk -F"[][{}]" '{print ...}' file
```

In general, you say `-F"[PATTERNS]"`.

#### Test

```
$ echo ".......{INFO1}.....[INFO2]...." | awk -F"[][{}]" '{print $2}'
INFO1
$ echo ".......{INFO1}.....[INFO2]...." | awk -F"[][{}]" '{print $4}'
INFO2
```

Comment: LOL, can you explain the syntax of the delimiters? Because I'm completely confused :-D Why does `[][{}]` work and `[{}][]` doesn't?

Comment: `[` is closed with `]`, except when `]` follows immediately the opening `[`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Quite weird, yeah :D As far as I've seen, `[]` together will make the regex close the block, so you have to "separate" them. I am trying to find a good reference, because I also had problems noticing what was the correct position for them.

Comment: Otherwise you can escape it ([see manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html#Bracket-Expressions)): `[{}[\]]` works too

Comment: @fredtantini Thx for the ref. But weirdly defferent from manual, with GNU awk 4.0.1, as to escape, I only can achieve it by [double escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867162/1819810). Here it is: using 3 delimiters `,` `/` `]` (note no `[`) to cut `aaa[bb,cc,dd/eee]`— it would be `-F '[,/\\]]'` or `-F "[,/\\\]]"`. Finally, `-F ',|/|]'` turns out easist way.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `{}` to the field separator:

```
~$ echo ".......{INFO1}.....[INFO2]...." | awk -F'[][{}]' '{print $2,$4}'
INFO1 INFO2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ echo '.......{INFO1}.....[INFO2]....' | awk -F'[][{}]' '{print $2}'
INFO1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '(?<=[{\[]).*?(?=[\]}])'
```