# Search for Double Quotes (") in the file and copy the whole line in different file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a requirement to read through all the files and look for <double quotes> (") and copy the whole line to a different file. The challenge is here that to identify the whole line when there is a new character in the line.

The file format is like this - values are separated with delimiter `|*|` and end with `|##|`.

In the attached (image), the highlighted in green should go to new file, Logic would be check for `"` and if it finds read line starting from (line after |##| to until next |##| )

[image: 1]

```
10338|*|BVL-O-G-01020-R4|*||*|BVL|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|CFC6E82284990A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|jmorlan|*|2011.12.21 15:52:01|##|
10358|*|BI-MED-CDMA-MCS-90-118-EXAM|*|Exam for 001-MCS-90-118:
Planning, Conducting and Reporting Post Marketing Surveillance "Studies and Safety Reporting from Non Trial Activities |*|GLOBAL_MEDICAL|*||*|Y|*|N|*||*|CFC6E822849A0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|finke|*|2012.04.30 04:23:27|##|
10342|*|BVL-O-4-01020-R7|*||*|DVL|*||*|Y|*|Y|*||*|RRFC6E82284990A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|sppa|*|2011.12.21 15:52:01|##|
```

Comment: `grep \" file >> newfile`?

Comment: it is unclear to me whether the whole line should go to the new file or only the parts between a pair of '|##|', since both is stated in your post

Comment: Yes, except you first need to split it into lines at |##|. You could use sed to convert the |##| pattern to newline.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that the sections between `|##|` should be considered as newline, next question is does you file contain any real newlines? If not, `grep` is probably not going to be very efficient as it works on a line-by-line basis. If any real newlines are supposed to be considered part of the text, then definitely, grep is going to be unhappy.

If you really want to do it in 1 go in grep:

grep -Eoz '(^|\|##\|)([^|]|\|[^#]|\|#[^#]|\|##[^|])*"([^|]|\|[^#]|\|#[^#]|\|##[^|])*(\|##\||$)'

This is looking for any sequence that starts with |##| (or is the start of the file) is followed by some characters, a quote, and some more characters, then ends with |##| (or end of file). By using -z grep will ignore any newlines in the file.
The complex "any characters" `([^|]|\|[^#]|\|#[^#]|\|##[^|])*` expression is because grep is greedy. It basically looks for repeating sequences that are not |##|. Perhaps turning off greed is good, but that will depend on the power of the regexp engine in your version of grep.

But much easier, and probably faster, to use sed to break up the records and inject "NULL" line-breaks:

sed 's/\|##\|/\x00/g' | grep -z '"'

This is simply replacing your end of line pattern |##| with the null character, then asking grep to find quote while treating null character as end of line.

Comment: another option: `awk -v RS='\\|##\\|' '/"/'`

Comment: @Sam no, you need the `ORS` also

Comment: i suppose you would... anyway the commands in this answer don't fully take that into acount either.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides two solutions a Gnu Awk solution and a POSIX version.

**POSIX awk**

```
awk '{r=r ? r "\n" $0 : $0}
     /\|##\|$/ { if (r ~ /"/) print r; r=""}' inputfile > outputfile
```

**GNU awk 1**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\|##\\|\n?";ORS="|##|\n"}/"/' inputfile > outputfile
```

**GNU awk 2**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\|##\\|\n?"}/"/{printf $0 RT}' inputfile > outputfile
```

On the sample data provided in the question, all provided solutions give the following output:

```
10358|*|BI-MED-CDMA-MCS-90-118-EXAM|*|Exam for 001-MCS-90-118:
Planning, Conducting and Reporting Post Marketing Surveillance "Studies and Safety Reporting from Non Trial Activities |*|GLOBAL_MEDICAL|*||*|Y|*|N|*||*|CFC6E822849A0A7AE040800AA5644B19|*|finke|*|2012.04.30 04:23:27|##|
```

***note:** It is possible that you are suffering from the Carriage Return problem if the file comes from a Windows machine. Pleas run `dos2unix` on the file before using it with these tools.*

---

***How does this work? (POSIX)***

Using a POSIX version of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) we can do

```
awk '{r=r ? r "\n" $0 : $0}
      /\|##\|$/ { if (r ~ /"/) print r; r=""}' inputfile > outputfile
```

The idea is to build a record `r` by appending every line to `r`. If the current line ends with `"|##|"`, then we check if the record `r` contains a <double quote> `"`. If this is the case, we print the record `r` and reset the record `r` to an empty string. If it does not contain the <double quote>, we just reset it.

***How does this work? (GNU)***

Using GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you can do this directly using the record separator `RS`

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\|##\\|\n?";ORS="|##|\n"}/"/' inputfile > outputfile
```

The idea here is that the file contains various records. The OP clearly stated that the information of a record is split in fields separated by `|*|`, but more importantly, the records themselves are separated by `|##|`. So in the presented example of the OP, the first record is line1 while the second record is spread over line 2 and line 3.

In [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you can define a record separator by means of the variable `RS`. In its default state, `RS` is the <newline> character `\n` which makes each line a separate record which can be referenced by `$0`. In POSIX, the record separator can only be a single character which separates the records, while in Gnu awk, this can be a regular expression (see addendum below).

Since the record separator of the OP is the string "|##|" followed all or not by a <newline> character `\n`, we need to define `RS=\\|##\\|\n?`. Why so complicated?

- the <pipe> `|` symbol is the OR operation (alternation operator) in a regular expression, so we need to escape it. But since string literals that are used as regular expressions are parsed twice, we also need to escape it twice. So `|` → `\\|` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25867768/8344060))
- the `\n?` is because it seems that the actual record separator is the string "|##|\n", but maybe some records do not have a newline character, especially the last record.

When you print records, using the `print` statement it automatically appends the output record separator `ORS` after each line. By default this is again a <newline> character `\n`. Since the record separator `RS` is not a part of the record `$0` you need to update the value `ORS` to `ORS="|##|\n"`. This time, not a regex, so you do not need to escape at all.

The statement `/"/` is a shorthand for `/"/{print $0}` which means *If the current record `$0` contains a <double quote> `"`, then print the current record `$0` followed by the output record separator `ORS`.*

**Note:** since we actually already use Gnu awk, we can actually reduce the whole thing even further to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\|##\\|\n?"}/"/{printf $0 RT}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Which makes use of the matched record separator `RT` that corresponds to the text found by `RS`. By replacing the `print` statement by a `printf` statement, we do not need to `ORS` anymore and just manually add `RT` to the record `$0`.

---

> **`RS`:** The input record separator. Its default value is a string containing a single newline character, which means that an input record consists of a single line of text. It can also be the null string, in which case records are separated by runs of blank lines. If it is a regexp, records are separated by matches of the regexp in the input text.
>
> The ability for `RS` to be a regular expression is a `gawk` extension. In most other AWK implementations, or if `gawk` is in compatibility mode (see Options), just the first character of `RS`’s value is used.
>
> **`ORS`:** The output record separator. It is output at the end of every print statement. Its default value is "\n", the newline character.
>
> **`RT`:** (GNU AWK specific) The input text that matched the text denoted by `RS`, the record separator. It is set every time a record is read.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables)</sub>**

Comment: Of course, you are going to explain RS and ORS and the need for both? :-)

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\|##\\|\n?";ORS="|##|\n"}/"/' Sample.dat> Sample1.dat   --------I have tried the awk option and its working for me . Thanks for the support

Comment: i will also try the Sed options and update you ... thanks for he helps ...

Comment: @Sumesh Can you provide a bit more information then _it is not working for me_. Which `awk` are you using (is it gawk, nawk, mawk, solaris, ...)

Comment: @Sumesh I have added a POSIX version to it, maybe this one works for you.